# Monero wallet error : failed to connect to daemon

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, daemon

I'm trying to set-up an old  laptop running Ubuntu OS to mine Monero as explained [here](https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-mine-monero) just for educational purposes. For this I tried creating a wallet as explained [here](https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-create-a-command-line-monero-wallet). However I'm getting the following error,

```
Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: http://localhost:18081.
 Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed.
 Please make sure daemon is running or change the daemon address using the 'set_daemon' command.
```

I'm quite new to cryptocurrency and Monero in particular, can anyone tell me what is going wrong here? and how to fix it?

Comment: You need to start the daemon (monerod) as separate software. That is, open a new terminal from directory of `monerod` and launch via `./monerod`. The wallet (`monero-wallet-cli`) will then be able to automatically connect (locally) to the daemon (that syncs the blockchain).

Answer (score 1):

I'd really recommend using the GUI wallet if you are new. The error message alludes that you did not start the daemon. The daemon is the monerod binary and not the wallet binary you ran. Please start ./monerod in another terminal. Do note that the daemon syncs the blockchain so decide now if you want to run a full node. If you don't want to, supply a remote node URL to the wallet instead.

If you really don't want to use the GUI wallet, you should setup your OS to start ./monerod on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Tou com o mesmo problema e ainda não consegui resolver nada.nao conecta o daemon
Alguém consegue me explicar como resolver isso.